# paypal check out node js error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined when i run my code

Tags: node.js, express, paypal

I have the following code it suppose to send the data to pay pal to process the payment but it keepsgeting this TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined i have gone through the code but i think the error is occuring "storeItems.get(item.id).price" when i try to get the "items id" for some reson thwe value is nt being seen

this is my request body contains the following array

```
{"items":[    
    {"id":"1", "quantity":1},    
    {"id":"2", "quantity":2},  
    {"id":"3", "quantity":3},    
    {"id":"4", "quantity":4}   
]}
```

```
app.post("/create-order", async (req, res) => {
 

  const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest()
  const total = req.body.items.reduce((sum, item) => {
    return sum + storeItems.get(item.id).price * item.quantity
  }, 0)
  console.log(total);
  request.prefer("return=representation")
  request.requestBody({
    intent: "CAPTURE",
    purchase_units: [
      {
        amount: {
          currency_code: "USD",
          value: total,
          breakdown: {
            item_total: {
              currency_code: "USD",
              value: total,
            },
          },
        },
        items: req.body.items.map(item => {
          const storeItem = storeItems.get(item.id)
          return {
            name: storeItem.name,
            unit_amount: {
              currency_code: "USD",
              value: storeItem.price,
            },
            quantity: item.quantity,
          }
        }),
      },
    ],
  })
  
  const order = await paypalClient.execute(request) 
})
```

Comment: Seems you need to do some basic debugging of what the values of your variables are at execution time, particularly `item` and `item.id` , -- and if they are always ok then what the storeItems.get() function returns when called.

Comment: i am getting my values from 

const storeItems = new Map([
  [1, { price: 100, name: "Learn React Today" }],
  [2, { price: 200, name: "Learn CSS Today" }],
])

when i check them they are ok

Comment: Your request has items not in that list? ...

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `storeItems.get(item.id)` in the `total` function is undefined.
From your comment, storeItems is defined like:

```
const storeItems = new Map([
  [1, { price: 100, name: "Learn React Today" }],
  [2, { price: 200, name: "Learn CSS Today" }],
])
```

So the issue must come from the `item`. Either it does not have an `id` property, or it is undefined, or its `id` property does not match any entry in your map.